# How to write makefile so that it ignores "irrelevant" changes?

Tags: makefile

Say I have a Makefile like this

```
B: A
    quick-custom-script < $< > $@

C: B
    slow-custom-script < $< > $@
```

Also assume that it may well happen that changes in `A` would produce the same `B`. I would like to achive that in such a case the complex making of `C` is left out because *that* is certainly unnecessary work when it has unchanged input.

My idea was to put the output of `quick-custom-script` to a temporary file, diff that against the current `B` and overwrite `B` only if differences are found.
In this case, the `C` rule would still see the old `B` and do nothing. Unfortunately, this produces another problem that I see (and perhaps more?): On any subsequent run, even without any changes made, `A` will be newer than the non-overwritten `B` and hence (even if it is quick) the first script will run - unnecesarily.

I think  this can somewhat be minimized as follows

```
Btemp: A
    quick-custom-script < $< > $@

B: Btemp
    diff -q $< $@ || cp $< $@

C: B
    slow-custom-script < $< > $@
```

Nevertheless I wonder if there is any smarter way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty close to the usual convention.  It puts the comparison into the same recipe, like this:

```
B: A
    quick-custom-script < $< > $@T
    $(move-if-change)
```

With this definition:

```
move-if-change = @if cmp -s $@ $@T ; then rm $@T ; else mv $@T $@; fi
```

This combination into one rule has the advantage that if `quick-custom-script` terminates abnormally and the makefile is run again, the recipe will start from scratch, and the partially written output file is discarded.

Using `cmp` is usually quicker than `diff`, and `mv` is atomic, so it avoids reintroducing the same potential corruption.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out corruption problems. Nevertheless, this usual convention still relies on quick-custom-script to be indeed very quick and cheap because it will *always* be run (as $@T gets removed one way or the other)?

Comment: Yes, but it's not clear if that's practically relevant. If `A` itself is built, you should `$(move-if-change)` to its recipe. If it is an original input file, then the question is how often no-op input file changes happen, and how long such build trees are used (so that `quick-custom-script` is needlessly invoked over and over again).